# Looking for in-memory caching solution

Tags: caching, grails, ehcache, grails-2.0

In our project we have to store current information about several devices. The devices transmit those information in regular intervals to the server. The server stores the received information in several tables and also updates objects in synchronized lists, which are showing the current states of the devices.

To avoid heavy database load some views access the cached objects over synchronised lists to display status information of the requested devices.

The synchronized lists are located within a service class and look like as follow:

```
private Map<Long, DeviceStatus> statusMap = java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Long, DeviceStatus>()) // key = unique id
```

The service API provides methods for updating, removing, ... list entries by id or other properties.

We're are not happy with the current solution, because you're not able to share status information across more running instances. Furthermore the is no possibility to monitor the memory usage of such lists.

We are thinking about two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

Introduction of a HSQLDB database (with the help of the dataSource plugin) to store the frequently updated information. With this solution all GORM features like findBY would be remain. Disadvantage: storage distribution between several system.

**Solution 2:**

Implement the POJO DeviceStatus as a domain class and make it cacheable. In future terracotta can be used to share the cached information over several systems. Disadvantage: we have no need to store this information in the database. Is there a way or option to store the domain class only in-memory. During start-up the DeviceStatus cache is initialized by fetching information from several data sources (=tables).

**Requirements:**

- Access cached objects with methods like findBy
- Distribution of cache over several systems (using ehcache and terracotta)

What do you think about those solutions and are there better solutions for the described scenario? Can we use the new introduced cache plugin for storing the status objects and access them by other attributes than the a unique key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using EhCache? EhCache can be used to cache any objects, not only domain classes (although you can use it as a 2nd level cache for Hibernate). You can set up EhCache to transparently overflow objects to disk when the in-memory cache is full to prevent out of memory situations.

If you need all your caches to be synchronized across nodes then you can use Terracotta as a distributed cache, and Terracotta is compatible with EhCache.

Otherwise your question seems a little unclear; do you need querying capabilities across these domain objects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at memcache http://memcached.org ? It's an open sourced in-memory caching system that's easy to set up.  You could add any available server to the pool.  You store data by key/value so just make sure whatever you're stuffing in it is serializable. It would run as an independent tier from your webapps, so any of your application instance can access it without needing terracotta which as I understand helps with your JVM cluster share memory.

Comment: at this time we decided to take ehcache. sorry for the very late answer!